# how to Install APK in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to install an app in Kotlin I have the File ready, using Download Manager I get the update of an app but after downloading it It opens and closes without installing. I also need Oreo permission for other cellphones

```
                var toInstall= File(uriString)
                val intent: Intent

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    val apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, 
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall)
                    intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    val apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall)
                    intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                }
                activity.startActivity(intent)
```

the provider in manifest

```
       <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.multilevel.provider"
        android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name=" android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: AFAIK, `ACTION_VIEW` is not supported for installation on newer versions of Android. Use `PackageInstaller`. See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/master/AppInstaller), covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q).

Comment: But ViewModelProviders is deprecated what should I use???

Comment: Replace `private lateinit var motor: MainMotor` with `private val motor: MainMotor by viewModels()` and delete the `motor` line in `onCreate()`.

Comment: "But ViewModelProviders is deprecated what should I use" -- `ViewModelProviders` overall is not deprecated. That project's particular use of it is, because that project is a couple of years old.

Comment: I copied both classes and added the rest to the main, that in my case is a fragment, but I have some mistakes like (open method, return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu), menu inflater, etc., plus I do not know where to write the URI, I do not know if instantiate the other classes, I do not understand. do you have an example?